# How to force refresh of GrandParent component from grandchild component with React hooks in SPFx

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, spfx

In the main component of a SPFx web part, I have a data load running in a   React.useEffect

```
const [jobsGets, setJobsGets] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
   {Some code to get data from SharePoint}
    });
  }, [jobsGets]);
```

So a refresh will happen when the value of "jobsGets" will change, right?

This component calls another component that calls another and the last has an event that should refresh by changing "jobsGets".
If I write a fanction and pass it down the props of each generation's component,

It ends running in the main component forever. So this is not a good solution.
How do I `setJobsGets(jobsGets+1);` from the grandchild components?

Any hint is welcome.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you are likely updating jobs at grandChild with `useEffect`, that runs on mount and every update. if you pass a second empty array `[]` param, this update will run only after first render if that's your specific case, avoiding retriggers:

```
// at some granchild
useEffect(() => { ...logic here }, [])
```

if useEffect should run after on specific param's update, you pass that param as argument to the array. useEffect will run only on changes for the params dependencies set on `[]`.

```
useEffect(() => { ...logic here }, [param])
```

you may also look at [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) for passing down state better at deep tree.